# How do I get template object data to persist in Meteor templates?

Tags: templates, meteor

I want to be able to set/get data of a template object when using template event handler functions. I have tried to set a variable at the point when the template is rendered and hoped it would be accessible later on, in this case when an element in the template is clicked by the users, but it isn't working:

```
<template name="fooBar">
    <div class="some_element">CLICK ME</div>
</template>

Template.fooBar.rendered = function(){
    this.templateVar = "Hello";
}

Template.fooBar.events({
    'click .some_element': function(e,t){
        alert(this.templateVar); // Should say 'Hello', but is 'undefined'.
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you able to use Sessions?

Comment: t.templateVar or Template.instance().templateVar

Comment: Template.instance got a [different behavior](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/PrzfPlYKYjk) on rendered and events handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion given by Sindis, this is the quickest way to solve the issue:

Instead of...

```
alert(this.templateVar);
```

... just do...

`alert(this.templateVar);` or `alert(Template.instance().templateVar);`

Answer (score 2):

Using  reactive-dict package, you can do like this.

**First** add it.

```
meteor add reactive-dict
```

**Second** create the templates. (note im using meteor 1.1 version)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.onRendered(function(){
       this.templateVar = new ReactiveDict(); //create the var templateVar
    })

   Template.hello.onRendered(function(){

     this.templateVar.set("hi", "hello"); //give them a value
   })

     Template.hello.events({
      'click .some_element': function(e,t){
         console.log(t.templateVar.get('hi')) //and print the value using the template instance.
      }
   });
 }
```